# Java terminal game

Tags: java, terminal, console

I am trying to create a game in a terminal for a school assignment. No pop out windows or anything. The problem is a bug in the game itself. the 'x' should move until it hits the wall, but it gets stuck inside the wall. I am only learning java and also any tips for future posts or programming are appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int coordx = 1;
        int coordy = 1;
        while (true) {

            // System.out.println("Move: ");
            String move = input.nextLine();
            switch (move) {
                case "a":
                    while (!wall(coordy - 1, coordx)) {
                        coordx--;
                    }
                    break;
                case "w":
                    while (!wall(coordy, coordx - 1)) {
                        coordy--;
                    }
                    break;
                case "d":
                    while (!wall(coordy + 1, coordx)) {
                        coordx++;
                    }
                    break;
                case "s":
                    while (!wall(coordy, coordx + 1)) {
                        coordy++;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            render(coordx, coordy);

        }

    }

    public static void render(int chary, int charx) {
        int[][] grid = new int[9][40];

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
                if (i == charx && j == chary) {
                    grid[i][j] = 0;
                    System.out.print("x");
                } else if (wall(i, j)) {
                    grid[i][j] = 2;
                    System.out.print("#");
                } else {
                    grid[i][j] = 1;
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean wall(int coordy, int coordx) {
        if (coordx == 0 || coordx == 39 || coordy == 0 || coordy == 8) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        // return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like little games like this very much and it's great to help somebody like you early on in their adventure threw programming.

I think you have some of the while contidions mixed up. For Example:

```
                case "a":
                    while (!wall(coordy - 1, coordx)) {
                        coordx--;
```

As far as I understand your game it should be:

```
                case "a":
                    while (!wall(coordy, coordx - 1)) {
                        coordx--;
```

Check the other conditions in your gameloob too.